# GAE/Java cron.xml in different modules overwrite each other?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, module, cron

I have application with 2 modules. In each module I have cron.xml definition of cron job that has sense only for that module. When I `gradle appengineUpdateCron` from module-1 it overwrites cron jobs for module-2. (GAE console shows Cron tasks only for module that was uploaded the last).

Is it meant to work that way?

Or are we forced to define cron jobs in module that has nothing to do with it in order to have all cron jobs defined in one file? (e.g. defining cron job for module-1 in cron.xml of module-2)

Comment: Hmm, I've found out that all cron jobs must be defined in default module.  [GAE Modules doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration). It's a bit counter-intuitive to define cron jobs for one module in some other module.

Answer (score 0):

The cron configuration is an **application** level configuration, not a **module** level one. All application level configurations are logically *attached* to the default module, they are listed in the "Optional configuration files" section in the modules doc you mentioned.

Comment: ok thanks for clarification. if it's an application level configuration, would it not make more sense to put it in application folder (where application.xml is) rather than default module folder ?